# android invalidate function is not called

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

when findsellectedtBt() called invalidate in the findSellectedBt() don't work. 
so onDraw() is not called.

why these codes don't work correctly ?

```
public class CustomView extends View {



private Typeface t;
private Paint paint;
private Buttons sellectedBt;


public CustomView(Context context) {
    ... }

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
...}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
...}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(isInEditMode()) return ;

    canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);

    switch(sellectedBt) {
        case ID:
            t = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL);
            paint.setTypeface(t);
            canvas.drawText("ID: 0000", 50, 100, paint);
        case PHOTO:
                    break;
        case LINE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void findSellectedBt(Buttons buttonId ) {
    sellectedBt = buttonId;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private CustomView customView;
private Button btId;
private CheckBox btPhoto;
private ToggleButton btLineOff;
private Button btClaer;
private ToggleButton btBlue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    customView = new CustomView(this);

    btId = (Button)findViewById(R.id.id);
    btPhoto = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.photo);

    btId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            System.out.println("idOnclick");
            customView.findSellectedBt(Buttons.ID);

        }
    });

    btPhoto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("photoChecked");

            if(arg1 == true)
                customView.findSellectedBt(Buttons.PHOTO);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

package com.example.hw4_200921275;

public enum Buttons {ID, PHOTO, LINE, CLEAR, BLUE}

Comment: Need to see when you're calling invalidate... is it from a separate thread, or the UI thread?

Comment: i can't distinguish separate thread and UI thread. what is difference?

Comment: Where are you calling `findSellectedBt`?

Comment: @ssantos 
public void findSellectedBt(Buttons buttonId ) {
    sellectedBt = buttonId;
    invalidate();
}
 in the bottom code

Comment: Yeah that's the definition of the function but I can't see any line calling `findSellectedBt(buttonsObject)`, is there any?

Comment: Yes, clling is in mainactivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Double check you're somewhere calling

```
findSellectedBt(buttonsObject);
```

By the way, notice the typo in `Sellected`.